# COPY FROM STDIN does not work in liquibase

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I'm trying to upload a lot of data from a .sql file using the COPY command for Postgresql.
I have those data in a `file.sql` in the following format :

```
COPY my_table(id, name, status)  FROM stdin; 
1   peter  active
1   steve  active
1   maria  active
\.
```

And my changeset like this:

```
<changeSet id="sqlFile-example" author="me" >
        <sqlFile encoding="UTF-8"
                 path="file.sql"
                 relativeToChangelogFile="true"
                 endDelimiter=";"
                 splitStatements="false"
        />
 </changeSet>
```

And get this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.3:update (default-cli) on
> project lincoln-soft: Error setting up or running Liquibase: Migration
> failed for change set
> src/main/resources/db/liquibase/db-changelog.xml::sqlFile-example::me
>
> [ERROR]      Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:   ERROR: unexpected message type 0x50 during COPY from stdin
>
> [ERROR]   Where:
> COPY my_table, line 1 [Failed SQL: COPY my_table(id, name, status)
> FROM stdin;
>
> [ERROR] 1       peter  active
>
> [ERROR] 1       steve  active
>
> [ERROR] 1       maria  active
>
> [ERROR] \.]

I there a way to upload those data by liquibase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Laurenz already mentioned: you can't use COPY FROM STDIN directly in JDBC (you can use the CopyManager API to implement that manually, but Liquibase doesn't support that and I also don't know of any plugin that would do that)

I would suggest you use Liquibase's built-in ability to load CSV (text) files. Put your input data in CSV file, e.g. `my_table_data.txt` with a header line for the columns:

```
id,name,status
1,peter,active
1,steve,active
1,maria,active
```

Then use `<loadData>` instead of running a SQL script:

```xml
<changeSet id="sqlFile-example" author="me" >
        <loadData tableName="my_table"
                  file="my_table_data.txt" 
                  separator=","
                  encoding="UTF-8">
</changeSet>
```

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name. I only have some problems formating my data like `my_table_data.txt`, because my real data has a table with about 30 columns, and 32.000 rows, and some data that has spaces inside, some null values and so on.

Comment: If you can import that data using COPY you can also import it using `<loadData>` you probably just need to provide a different separator and maybe a quote character

Answer (score 6):

Finally got a solution, as @a_horse_with_no_name and @Laurenz Albe
 mentioned, can't use `COPY FROM STDIN` directly in JDBC, so I used `pg_dump` to generate insert statements like this:

`pg_dump --table=public.my_table --data-only --column-inserts my_databse > /tmp/my_table_data.sql`

It gives me a file `my_table_data.sql` with the inserts statements like this:

```
INSERT INTO public.my_table (id, name, status) VALUES (1,peter,active);
INSERT INTO public.my_table (id, name, status) VALUES (1,peter,active);
INSERT INTO public.my_table (id, name, status) VALUES (1,peter,active);
```

And then I use this liquibase Chageset to upload the sql file:

```xml
<changeSet id="sqlFile-example" author="me" >
     <sqlFile encoding="UTF-8"
           path="my_table_data.sql"
           relativeToChangelogFile="true"
           splitStatements="true"
           stripComments="true"
     />
</changeSet>
```

It works for me

Answer (score 2):

Mixing the `COPY` statement and the data in the same file only works in `psql` scripts.

There is support for `COPY` in the JDBC driver, but you'd have to use the `CopyManager` explicitly.

You should use `INSERT` statements in your script. If you want to load a `pg_dump` with the JDBC driver, use `pg_dump --inserts` (but expect slower performance).

Comment: Bit of a shame that pg_dump defaults to copy from stdin rather than inserts, but the docs do point out that inserts are slower. Such is life.